# How to integrate Google Form with WhatsApp for auto text chat confirmation for customer details?

Tags: google-forms, whatsapp

I want to know how we can achieve the solution to this problem in easiest way possible. So, I have a Google form where my executive fills in the details of the customer. I want to send a WhatsApp text to the customer once the entry in the Google form is done and have his confirmation on WhatsApp in return. For example:

1. Customer will get text with his details in it on WhatsApp with "Do you confirm?" question and auto text button below it as "Yes" or "No".
2. The customer will select either option and depending on that reply the next auto WhatsApp text should trigger like thank you or request him to update the details with the executive.

In the scenario, integration of WhatsApp with Google form is needed and for that I am sort of thinking of using integrately.com website that solves my problem a bit but not sure how to configure all this. Can anyone point me to right direction?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.